# How to hide the delete button when I call onClick function to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on a code where I need to have an option of deleting.

When you click on any of the number listed you will get and (button) option to delete. but Iam unable to hide (Delete button) once the button is clicked.

Can any guide me how to do this.

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/zrWo2Dfw86DAhR6sos62?p=preview)

```
    <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="e in arr track by $index">
    <span ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex=$index">{{ e }} <button ng-show="$parent.selectedIndex == $index" >delete</button></button></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you have 2 of `</button>`

Comment: and use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

Comment: And how to do that @Ivan

Comment: Yes @gianlucatursi but that wont solve the issue.

Comment: You want to hide the delete but when delete button is clicked ?

Comment: Yes exactly @Loading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you wanted to only hide delete button once its click(when visible)

Change you ng-click to toggle `selectedIndex` value

```
ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex!=$index?$parent.selectedIndex=$index:$parent.selectedIndex = null"
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/TLKT7QSAp4hLQ4JQa0ww?p=preview)

---

Cleaner solution without using `$parent` notation

```
<p>click to select:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="e in arr track by $index">
    <span ng-click="changeIndex($index)">{{ e }} 
      <button ng-show="selectedIndex == $index">delete</button></button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.selectedIndex = undefined;
$scope.changeIndex = function(index){
  return $scope.selectedIndex != index? $scope.selectedIndex=index:$scope.selectedIndex = null
}
```

[**Update Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1kEA6jGdbUmQzjdU0mln?p=preview)

Though using `$parent` anotation before scope variable creates a tight coupling between variable, instead I'd prefer you to use `Dot Rule` while defining model in angular **OR** another best way would be to use follow `controllerAs` pattern 
while defining models.

Comment: Your code will work fine but with one issue. for the first list the delete button wont hide. If that will work fine then I would like accept your answer. @Pankaj Parkar

Comment: @User123 that's becuse `$index 0` tends to become `1`(which is true) when I do `!0`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a state variable to the button

http://plnkr.co/edit/o3paTVPZG5Me568pzIL9?p=preview

add this to Controller

```
$scope.buttonClicked=false;

$scope.toggleButton = function(e) {
  $scope.buttonClicked=!$scope.buttonClicked;
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```

then

```
<span ng-click="$parent.selectedIndex=$index; $parent.buttonClicked=false">{{ e }} <button ng-show="$parent.selectedIndex == $index && !$parent.buttonClicked" ng-click="$parent.toggleButton($event)">delete</button></span>
```

e.stopPropagation() is needed because when you click on the button the click event propagates to span and li tag also and that set buttonClicked to false again.